# Is there a faster (computationally) way than Mesh Boolean to poke holes into a grid plane in Geometry nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, optimization

I have a grid plane that should appear as an actual grid, but with holes at arbitrary points where the stars are (from this video I made https://youtu.be/tso5pSzBRDo). I'm currently using a mesh grid with a Mesh Boolean node that pokes holes with a cylinder. The grid is just a brick texture with alpha transparency. This works. But it's so incredible slow once you start adding more cylinders, it slows the whole program down and I have to realize it or turn it off to work.

Is there another way to poke holes into a grid mesh without using a Mesh Boolean?

[image: Node Tree]

[image: Rendered View]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this approach:

[image]

of course you have to change the random value -> set position to your positions you need. It's just an example.

Comment: Thank you! That works so much better.

Comment: Good thinking :)

Comment: I agree this is smart. I wonder what happens when the circle density increases and some circles collide with each other

Comment: @Gorgious: then my solution wouldn't work ;)